# Cant get the image to show in Umbraco7 with razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I have used the media picker as data type for the type, for which the user is going to choose what image they want as the deal image.

But for some reason i can't get the razor syntax to show the image. If I make an If statement to check if the page contains an image then it won't. I think this is a problem that occurs because i have misunderstood something.

My current razor statement:

```
<img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("deal1image")).Url" />
```

The above code won't show anything.

Hope any of you can guide me to what i do wrong and evt. stuff I'm missing.

This is how my current home.cshtml looks like:

```
 @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!--Image here-->
        <img src="@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.deal1image).Url" />


        <div class="thumbnail thumbnailcustom thumbnailbg1">
            <h3>@Umbraco.Field("dealtitle1")</h3>
            <p>@Umbraco.Field("dealdescription1")</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!--Image here-->
        <div class="thumbnail thumbnailcustom thumbnailbg2">
            <h3>@Umbraco.Field("dealtitle2")</h3>
            <p>@Umbraco.Field("dealdescription2")</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!--Image here-->
        <div class="thumbnail thumbnailcustom thumbnailbg3">
            <h3>@Umbraco.Field("dealtitle3")</h3>
            <p>@Umbraco.Field("dealdescription3")</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you check what Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("deal1image") returns, in debug? And also if @Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("deal1image")).Url does not return an empty string, indeed ?

Comment: also, I am not sure you should use Umbraco.TypedMedia. At least I have never done so, I use Umbraco.Media.

Comment: I just tried to check if value is null and it is. In the Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("deal1image") part then "deal1image" is the datatype alias right?

Comment: How would you use the @Umbraco.Media?

Comment: what you pass into GetPropertyValue should be the desired documentType property's alias

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would display an image in razor?

Comment: Umbraco.media: say you are rendering the view for a page that represents node "x" in the umbraco tree - you should have a property in x document's type that is an image or something like that (in your case, an image picker) - say this property has an alias of "myImage". Then in the view razor you do "umbraco.media(myImage.ToString() or myImage.Id (I'm not sure which one, check in debug to see which returns the node id of the image element)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Umbraco.Media` to get the media. So like this

```
<img src="@Umbraco.Media(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("deal1image").ToString()).Url" />
```

Or

```
<img src="@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.deal1image).Url" />
```

Comment: @McBoman does the current page contain a Media field with the alias "deal1image"? If so, try to write **@CurrentPage.deal1image** and see if its returning a Id. The code above is the correct way to get a media item.

Comment: It doesn't I think i have setup the media in a wrong way in the document type.

Answer (score 0):

An example of using Umbraco.Media:

```
var myPage = CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf().Where("DocumentTypeAlias == @0", "yourPageAlias").First();

Umbraco.Media(myPage.myImage.ToString()).Url
```

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it could help countless others.

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/media-picker) on *OUR Umbraco* offers two solutions:

**Typed:**

```
@if (Model.Content.HasValue("caseStudyImages"))
{
    var caseStudyImagesList = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("caseStudyImages").Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse);
    var caseStudyImagesCollection = Umbraco.TypedMedia(caseStudyImagesList).Where(x => x != null);

    foreach (var caseStudyImage in caseStudyImagesCollection)
        {      
            <img src="@caseStudyImage.Url" style="width:300px;height:300px" />      
        }                                                               
}
```

**Dynamic:**

```
@if (CurrentPage.HasValue("caseStudyImages"))
{
    var caseStudyImagesList = CurrentPage.CaseStudyImages.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var caseStudyImagesCollection = Umbraco.Media(caseStudyImagesList);

    foreach (var caseStudyImage in caseStudyImagesCollection)
    {
        <img src="@caseStudyImage.Url" style="width:300px;height:300px" />
    }
}
```

Also, double check your media picker data type alias. Typos are rather common in this part.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit clunky compared to other answers but this is what I currently have.

```
var imageId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("eventPoster"); // gets node id
var evId = evpId.Id; // gets image id
var evMd = Umbraco.Media(evId); // I believe this turns the id into a string
var evUrl = evMd.Url; // gets the url of the string
```