# Wont show image instead it gives error on my masterpage layout. Umbraco7, razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

Yesterday I posted a question about why i couldn't get my image to show.
[Cant get the image to show in Umbraco7 with razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301757/cant-get-the-image-to-show-in-umbraco7-with-razor)

I got great and right answers.

The problem is when i use those examples of how to get image to show then i get an error like this:

```
Line 1:  @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
Line 2:  @{
Line 3:      Layout = "Master.cshtml";
Line 4:  }
Line 5:  <div class="container">
```

If I remove this:

```
 <img src="@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.deal1image).Url" />
```

Then everything is fine but just without any images.

In my document type called Home have i used the Media Picker as generic property. Alias is deal1image. And they are under the tab called Deals.

Hope one of you can help me.

This is the whole error:

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params string[])'

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params string[])'

```
Line 1:  @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
Line 2:  @{
Line 3:      Layout = "Master.cshtml";
Line 4:  }
Line 5:  <div class="container">
```

Stack trace:

```
[RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.Media(params string[])']
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , UmbracoHelper , Object ) +226
   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) +686
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Bo\Google Drev\ASPNET\SvaleredenCamping\SvaleredenCamping\Views\Home.cshtml:3
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +96
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +257
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   Umbraco.Core.Profiling.ProfilingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +294
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +175
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651188
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

The error is telling you it doesn't know which method to use because "deal1image" doesn't return anything. So you have to check if "deal1image" has any value. Like this:

```
@if(CurrentPage.HasValue("deal1image"))
{
   <img src="@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.deal1image).Url" />
}
```

Are you 1000 percent sure that "deal1image" is the alias of your property, and that you selected any media item in umbraco?

Comment: I have posted the whole error now. It doesn't print anything.